# difference of two series converges, but when does each converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My question below was stupid. I was meaning to ask the question in a more specific context. (Without mentioning the context, it's a stupid question!) Please ignore this question.

=====================================

Consider two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ in a compact set. Assume $|a_n-b_n| \leq \frac{C}{n}$. Then $a_n - b_n$ converges to zero; however, $a_n$ and $b_n$ may not converge.

My question is: again, consider two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ in a compact set. Assume $|a_n-b_n| \leq \frac{C}{n^2}$. Do $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge? (My intuition says yes since $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, but $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges) How do I show it? Or is it NOT true?

Comment: Did you try checking some simple examples?

Comment: John Ma already gave a counterexmple. In fact, what your condition ensures is that the sequence $a_1+\dots+a_n-(b_1+\dots+b_n)$ converges, because it is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true:

$$a_n = b_n = (-1)^n$$

does not converge in $[-1, 1]$.